# Stuck with Oracle db permissions when creating OLAP Dimension through AWM

Tags: oracle, olap

I want to create olap cube through AWM.
I managed to create workspace, but when I try to create first dimension I get permission error.
I've given user (MANDRI) all grants as stated here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28124/start.htm#OLAUG200, but I'm still getting error.

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
An error has occurred on the server
Error class: Express Failure
Server error descriptions:
DPR: cannot create server cursor, Generic at TxsOqDefinitionManager::generic<CommitRoot>
INI: XOQ-00289: error executing DDL "(CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "MANDRI"."CATEGORY_VIEW" AS
SELECT
"DIM_KEY",
"LEVEL_NAME",
"MEMBER_TYPE",
"DIM_ORDER",
"LONG_DESCRIPTION",
"SHORT_DESCRIPTION",
"CATEGORY_LONG_DESCRIPTIO",
"CATEGORY_SHORT_DESCRIPTI",
"SUBCATEGORY_LONG_DESCRIP",
"SUBCATEGORY_SHORT_DESCRI"
FROM TABLE(CUBE_TABLE('"MANDRI"."CATEGORY"') )
)" for metadata object "(MANDRI.CATEGORY)", Generic at TxsOqPersistentMetadataContext::executeDDL
INI: XOQ-00106: SQL query failed: "(ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
)", Generic at TxsRdbSQLStatement::execute()
```

These are the privileges the user has:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY
DEBUG CONNECT SESSION
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE ANY CUBE DIMENSION
CREATE DIMENSION
CREATE CUBE DIMENSION
CREATE ANY DIMENSION
CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
ADVISOR
CREATE TYPE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

The user was missing `GRANT CREATE VIEW`. It would be nice to have that included in the documentation.